# Rearranging the columns of my heatmap using python's seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, heatmap

I'm trying to visualize the following .csv data:

```
Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13,Q14,Q15,Q16,Q17,Q18,Q19,Q20
4,4,2,2,4,2,3,5,3,4,2,5,2,1,4,4,2,1,5,2
2,2,4,4,4,2,2,2,4,4,2,4,2,2,3,2,2,4,5,2
4,5,4,1,4,2,2,4,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,4,4,2,5,4
3,4,2,4,4,2,2,2,4,3,2,4,4,3,3,4,2,4,5,1
4,4,3,2,4,3,4,5,4,3,1,5,3,2,4,2,2,3,4,2
4,5,2,3,5,1,3,4,3,3,1,2,4,4,5,4,1,4,5,4
5,5,5,2,4,3,2,4,4,2,2,4,4,2,4,2,2,4,4,5
4,4,3,1,5,3,2,4,2,2,1,4,4,2,4,1,2,5,5,3
1,3,5,2,4,4,3,1,4,4,2,3,1,4,3,4,3,3,4,1
3,3,5,2,4,2,4,4,3,4,1,5,4,2,1,2,2,4,5,2
```

Here's my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
         
df =  pd.read_csv('data.csv') 

map = sns.clustermap(df, annot=True, linewidths=2, linecolor='yellow', metric="correlation", method="single")

plt.show()
```

Which returns:

[image: heatmap]

I want to rearrange my heatmap and order it column-wise by the **frequency** of each response. For example, The column `Q5` has the value `4` repeated 8 times (more than any other column), so it should be the first column. Columns `17` and `19` have a value that is repeated 7 times, so they should come in second and third (exact order doesn't matter). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the order and reindex before using the data in `clustermap`:

```
order = (df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
           .max()
           .sort_values(ascending=False)
           .index
         )

import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.clustermap(df[order], col_cluster=False, annot=True, linewidths=2, linecolor='yellow', metric="correlation", method="single")
```

Output:

[image]